# Always execute tests before sonar-scanner command to see the actual code coverage in Sonar

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

The project I'm working on has Sonar set up. My team also wants to see the code test coverage when running the `sonar-scanner`.

[image]

The project is built with Angular, and to see the actual coverage in Sonar, I have to run `ng test` before running `sonar-scanner`, so that the lcov.info is updated beforehand.

Is there any way to run `ng test` and then `sonar-scanner` afterwards with only one instead of two commands?

Answer (score 1):

Use the package.json scripting section to simplify running multiple commands together:

package.json

`"scripts" {
  "test": "ng test && sonar-scanner"
}`

You can then run as:
`npm run test`